# Find wake on lan

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios

I didn’t find wake on lan in bios setting
What should I do?
I want to turn on my PC when I’m outside.
I want to turn on my PC with anydesk

[image: power management setup]
[image: advanced bios features]

Comment: Most likely it's PME Event Wake Up setting (Power Management). It may be termed differently in different Firmware's. On my MSI Board it's called PCIE Wake Up.

Comment: It is turned on.but I can’t turn on my pc when it is sleep

Comment: *PME Event Wake Up* is related to mouse not LAN.  It doesn’t appear your device supports Wake On LAN, which isn’t surprising given its age.

Comment: I suggest you provide complete details about your hardware/software/application used. OS level / Network Adopter level settings, router settings if any and what exactly you are doing to wake up your PC. Check the details of each and every BIOS function under Power Management documented in the motherboard manual.